# keeping Python script alive constantly to check for changes

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I am trying write a Python script to monitor a GPIO pin on the raspberry Pi continually. I wrote a script using event_detection, but it ends on completion. Is there any way to keep it checking for changes to the GPIO pin?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

pin=37

GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN)

def alarmChange(channel):
    if(GPIO.input(pin)):
        print 'Sensor tripped',channel
    else:
        print 'sensor no longer tripped', channel

GPIO.add_event_detect(pin, GPIO.BOTH, callback=alarmChange)

GPIO.cleanup()
print "DONE....I never want to get here, unless I kill the process"
```

Comment: That would work, I am new to python however and was hoping there is a more elegant solution

Comment: You should not use a while loop by itself, what happens if the pin fires while you are sleeping?

Comment: If i just add a while loop at the bottom of my code (with a random variable assignment, not sleep) it seems to work fine

Comment: look at the code around the 10 minute mark http://pyvideo.org/video/2942/using-asyncio-aka-tulip-for-home-automation

Comment: That looks very interesting, unfortunately Im stuck with python 2.7

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trollius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while` loop with a dummy `sleep` content:

```
import time

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)  # 1s
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Bye!")
```